# Eclipse Indigo and SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using SVN with Eclipse. There appears a RED EXCLAMATION mark next to some of the resources in my IDE while others show a database icon. Also, there are some faded numbers next to each folder. What do all these mean? How can I remove the RED EXCLAMATION marks and the numbers?

Comment: can you show a screen shot of the problem ???

Comment: [Here is a screen shot](http://imm.io/SUJ7)

Comment: screen shot helped me a lot see my answer

Answer (score 2):

The red Exclamation sign shows the build path errors, as you can see the error that i  have missing a jar file that is why it is showing this mark, if i remove this jar from build path or if i add the jar at proper location this error will get removed. See the image.

[image: here is the image show the difference]

1: That number showing the version of the document, version that SVN manage, when you will make some changes in any document and commit it at SVN this version number will get updated.

2: In your case hopefully that image and doc file (i-e jpg, png and docx) does not exist on that location properly. to remove this refresh the work space and rebuild the project.

3: One more thing may be you know that but there is a  (>) greater then sign that show that this file is modified and not committed yet at SVN as soon as you commit it at SVN that sing will get removed.

Hope all this will help you...

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Only thing, the objects do exist in the workspace as well as on the dev server in the  same locations and with the same names. still the Red EXCLAMATION marks comes up with some resources. 

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll UPVOTE it.
Coz for me the exclamation marks still show up for two normal directories which have no JAVA resources in it. So it can't be a build path error.

It only shows up for ATTACHMENTS and TEMP directory. Are they by any chance reserved directories?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22904/discussion-between-user1872371-and-sfah)